# Add colored sidelines to headline using CSS

Tags: css, less

I'm trying to add colored sidelines to a headline on a page using CSS, this is what I've come up with so far (using LESS hence the nested properties) -

```
h2 {
    font-size: 2em;
    color: @black;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    &:before {
        position: absolute;
        top: 1em; // 50% of h2 font-size
        left: 100px;
        content: '';
        border-bottom: 1px solid @orange;
        width: 100px;
    }
    &:after {
        position: absolute;
        top: 1em;
        right: 100px;
        content: '';
        border-bottom: 1px solid @orange;
        width: 100px;
    }
}
```

This gives me a line at the bottom (using border-bottom property) on both sides of the headline, but I want them to be vertically centered to the headline's height. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position:relative`, on your H2 and use `position:absolute` with the proper top/left/right/bottom for your `:before` and `:after`.

Comment: Great, thanks! For anyone who's interested I've updated the code.

Comment: Glad to help. Please select the answer by pressing the checkmark to the left.